# Convert color image png into color css gradient

Tags: css, png

I want to convert this PNG image into a CSS gradient color. How can I do this if I have this PNG file?

[image: Image used for header with repeat-x]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the gradient CSS rule?

```css
#grad {
    background: linear-gradient(black, white); /* Standard syntax */
}

#grad2 {
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad">
  <br><br>
</div>

<div id="grad2">
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Some reading: [CSS Gradients](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)